# Do I have to use get_instance() in every helper function that needs access to native resources?

Tags: codeigniter, helper

I have many helper functions that require access to get_instance(). For example, here is a function to get a list of members for use in a dropdown:-

```
function get_members_list()
{
    $EE =& get_instance();
    $EE->load->model('member_model'); 
    // rest of my code 
    return $members_list;
}
```

I put it in a helper because there's a lot of extra code in here, something I would not consider suitable for model, but more for a controller. And then because several libraries/controllers are accessing it, I thought move it a helper.

So my question is, is it OK to use get_instance() and load helpers, within helper functions? I have get_instance() used many times in my helper file, because each function needs to call it.

Or is there a way for helpers to access get_instance() that is already loaded in the controller/library that is loading the helper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in a library.

How you organize things is really up to personal preference, but having a library would make the most sense. You can group it by data type, or just have a single library class for key/value data (for use in drop downs).

Comment: I agree. Create a library that bootstraps the instance and then autoload that library so that it's available in all of your controllers. Alternatively, you could simply get a reference in the constructor of your class.

Comment: I created a helper as it includes many unrelated functions. Would you create a "general" library that includes all the unrelated methods that need get_instance or seperate small libraries for each one? I usually see a library that has related methods rather than general ones that do different things.

Comment: It depends on your app. At this point, you're over thinking it. If you have a few of these functions, put them in a single library. If it starts getting big, make a bunch of smaller libraries (those could inherit from a base library the makes $CI available to all of them).